# How to handle Async Notification in Pyjamas?

Tags: javascript, python, pyjamas

I am writing a web application using **Pyjamas.** .

The core functionality of my application is to show some Events which are generated **asynchronously**, in an HTML table (using the corresponding pyjamas widget).

Is it possible to send these **notifications** to the `pyjamas` application running in the browser?

I have been looking for an example without success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if you are familiar with the pyjamas bookreader?
If not, there's a lot of information and some examples about ajax over there.

http://pyjs.org/book/Bookreader.html#Rest%20of%20the%20World